# Access Database on server, installing an applicaiton that uses access database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

1) I am  developing a desktop application that connects to a access database to store some information. This access database is on a server. I can get to that server using FTP sequence. The server also has the capability to establish connection to access database. Right now, my application downloads the database file into a folder on the computer edits it and puts it back on the server. I would really love to know if its possible to connect to the access database, make changes to it all without downloading it so that I can save time.

2) If its not possible to do what I was asking for in question 1. Say, I share my application with my colleges and I want them to be able to do the same with the database editing. after I make an .exe file out of my project and send it to them. Do they need to install ACE.oledb.12 on every computer that I want to run it on?

Comment: Neither JET nor ACE shine when connecting to remote databases (or even local ones). Just use a database server.

Comment: this reference may help: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/split-an-access-database-HA010342026.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As Access is a file based system rather than a dedicated database server, "remote connections" don't exactly exist as all data processing has to be done locally. However as long as you are able to setup either a VPN to the server where the Access file is stored, or even better map the path as a network drive then you should be able to access it without having to download the file first.  If you only have FTP access though then it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @Remou Yeah, I'm thinking perhaps SQL Server Express might be a nice choice for this one

Comment: I work at a community college and they would not install SQL server. I am limited to use just accessdatabase

Comment: @desktopmaker SQL Server 'Express' is freeware, a watered down version of the full SQL Server but still as capable as Access, just wondered in case it was a cost restriction. If still not an option then I've outlined the only real options available with Access.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are using is Jet/ACE, the database that Access normally uses, the other users will at least have to have the [drivers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=13255), which are free, or if you are working within Access itself, you will need the [runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/search.aspx?q=access%20runtime), also free.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your terminology you using is wrong. You don't connect to a word file. You don't connect to a power point file.

So you have to keep in mind here you are not really connecting to some text file or mdb file that just happens to be sitting on a hard drive.

You are thus simply opening a file.

I mean it is silly to say we connect to a word file, or we connect to a Power point file. So in the case of the office suite and those basic simple files that resides on the disk drive?

We are talking about plane Jane windows file.

A horse is a horse is a horse.

A file is a file is a file.

So you don't connect to the jpg file sitting on the hard drive, you OPEN the jpg file. So if you talking about your current setup it best to use the correct terminology here. You are not connecting to that Access accDB file, but are in fact opening a PLANE JANE windows file. If you look close at your connection string, it will ALWAYS have a fully qualified windows path name in it that resolves to a file sitting on a folder.

So if you place that file on some server, say web server, then then you still faced with having to open that windows file. This is NOT ANY different than wanting to open a power point file. That means if you going to connect over the internet then you need to EXTEND the windows file system (this means you will need some kind of VPN). At the end of the day, if you cannot use windows networking to browse and open the folder where that file resides, then you cannot open that file with Access (or more specific in your case the JET data engine).

So for example, if the server where the file resides is a non windows box, say Linux, then you need to "add or use" or "install" the windows file and networking system on that box. A common choice in Linux is to install and run Samba on that computer.

Keep in mind that in the case of using SQL server, then you are connecting to a SERVICE running ON THAT server. In this case then you not opening a file on the remote box, but are simply are using a socket (TCP/IP) connection to some service. So you not just opening a silly old windows file that happens to be an accdb file on that system in this case.

So as such when you use FTP or http, these are not real "windows" networking systems that allow you to open + use a plane Jane windows file.

FTP will require the WHOLE FILE to be downloaded local.

PROBLEM!
If the web site or web server has the accDB file open, then how are you going to have the web server CLOSE the file BEFORE you upload and OVERWRITE the file? In other words, if that file is open by the web server, then you should NOT be making a copy and even downloading a copy via FTP until the SERVER AND WEB SITE CLOSES THE FILE! This means you NEED permission to STOP the web server while you do this!

So as such, just keep in mind the concept here that you are NOT connecting to some file, but you are just going to OPEN the file. You need to be able to OPEN the file, and you need to be using the windows networking system to do this open file in the case of Access. I mean, you don't have to install Access(JET) on the target computer. You don't have to install Power Point on the target computer to open a power point file.

You don't have to install word on that system to open a word file.

You don't have to install Excel on that system to open an Excel file.

So you are ONLY opening a file that just happens to be on some other computer.

So the Access database engine and software MUST be installed on your computer (no .exe possible here). You can most certainly package up your application as an installable windows application that then can be installed on each computer. So a free edition of the Access runtime is available, but you still going to have to install that free version of Access on computers that use Access, even if it is the free runtime edition. However, these days, I not really aware of any popular development system that produces just .exe files without requiring a runtime of some kind, be it .net, VB6, Java, or in this case Access – so some kind of support and runtime files are quite much a common requirement in most systems in use today.

So, just keep in mind you are opening a plane Jane windows file.

As such, your path name of http, or FTP is not a allowed windows path name and is not a windows file/networking system. As such a path name has nothing to do with windows networking and opening of a simple file sitting on the hard disk. So HTTP or FTP etc. are not based on windows networking and file system.

I don’t think this basic concept is too hard to grasp, but at the end of the day the concept you need to grasp and learn is that when you open a windows file sitting in a folder on the hard drive, then then will you need the windows file system to open such files. The idea and concept of opening a file in a folder might be new to you, but it is a basic requirement and understanding you need to solve this issue.

As noted, you can consider a VPN, but I explain why such a setup is not going to work in this article:

Using a wan with ms-access? How fast, how far?

http://www.kallal.ca/Wan/Wans.html

(do read the above – as it explains that you CAN open such files over the internet, but ALSO explains that such connections are WAY TOO SLOW! – remember high speed internet is WAY TOO SLOW here for this use!).

I suppose another possibility would be to consider the new web publishing ability that Access has. In the following video note how I switch to running the Access application 100% in the browser. The resulting application does not need any ActiveX or Silverlight. So the web pages run + work fine on my smartphone and even my iPad.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

So you can use the new web publishing feature, and that would allow one to use http: to use the application